# RegEx - Find and Replace while ignoring a number in the middle?

Tags: c#, regex

In the middle of a long string, I am looking for "No. 1234. "

The number (1234) in my example above can be any length whole number. It also has to match on the space at the end.

So I am looking for examples:

> 1) This is a test No. 42. Hello Nice People
>   2) I have no idea wtf No. 1234412344124. I am doing.

I have figured out a way to match on this pattern with the following regex:
(No. [\d]{1,}. )'

What I cannot figure out, though, is how to do one simple thing when finding a match: Replace that last period with a darn comma!

So, with the two examples up above, I want to transform them into:

> 1) This is a test No. 42, Hello Nice People
>   2) I have no idea wtf No. 1234412344124, I am doing.

(Notice the commas now after the numbers)

How might one do this in C# and RegEx? Thank you!

EDIT:
Another way of looking at this is...

I can do this easily and have for years:
str = Replace(str, "Find this", "Replace it with this")

However, how can I do that by combining regex and the unknown portion of the string in the middle to replace the last period (not to be confused with the last character since the last character still needs to be a space)

- This is a test No. 42. Hello Nice People
- This is a test No. (some unknown length number). Hello Nice People
- becomes
- This is a test No. 42, Hello Nice People
- This is a test No. (some unknown length number), Hello Nice People

(Notice the comma)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you are essentially trying to match two adjacent groups, "\d+" and ". " then replace the second with ", ".

```
var r = new Regex(@"(\d+)(\. )");
var input = "This is a test No. 42. Hello Nice People";
var output = r.Replace(input, "$1, ");
```

Use the parenthesis to match two groups then with replace keep the first group and dump in the ", ".

Edit: derp, escape that period.

Comment: That is beautiful! You are correct. If it wasn't painfully obvious, I should have just mentioned that I am new to RegEx. But, yes, you just recognized and solved my problem! I was not even aware of "groups" and I am in need of doing some reading/learning of RegEx.

Thank you very much, neilh.

Comment: Hey @neilh,

I noticed today that this has one small flaw that I cannot get passed... if it matches on a number that is longer than 1 digit, then it will only REPLACE the first digit.

Example:
"No. 422. " becomes "No. 4, " and it ignores the other digits. Ideas?

Thank you again, buddy!

Comment: @user3038032, can you post the code you're using? I'm having difficulty replicating the behavior you describe.

Comment: var r = new Regex(@"(No. \d+)(.) ");
        var output = r.Replace(strName, "$1, ");
        return output;

Comment: Thank you again, @neilh.

I am still hacking away at it. I don't understand it still.

Comment: @RandyWhirl, running the test cases from your post through that code returns the expected results ("This is a test No. 42, Hello Nice People" and "I have no idea wtf No. 1234412344124, I am doing."). Is there another input string that you're having trouble with?

Comment: I believe the problem is solved by changing: "(\d+)(.) " to "(\d+)(\.) "

(notice the backslash before the last period).

Answer (score 1):

**Edit - #1:**

neilh's way is much better!

Ok, i know the code looks ugly.. i don't know how to edit the last char of a match directly in a regex

```
string[] stringhe = new string[5] {
    "This is a test No. 42, Hello Nice People",
    "I have no idea wtf No. 1234412344124. I am doing.",
    "Very long No.                        74385748957348957893458934; Hello World",
    "Nope No. 48394839!!!",
    "Nope"
};

Regex reg = new Regex(@"No.\s*([0-9]+)");

Match match;
int idx = 0;

StringBuilder builder;
foreach(string stringa in stringhe)
{
    match = reg.Match(stringa);

    if (match.Success)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("No. Stringa #" + idx + ": " + stringhe[idx]);

        int indexEnd = match.Groups[1].Index + match.Groups[1].Length;

        builder = new StringBuilder(stringa);
        builder[indexEnd] = '.';

        stringhe[idx] = builder.ToString();
        Console.WriteLine("New String: " + stringhe[idx]);
    }

    ++idx;
}

Console.ReadKey(true);
```

If you want to edit the char after the number of if it's a ',':

int indexEnd = match.Groups[1].Index + match.Groups[1].Length;

```
if (stringa[indexEnd] == ',')
{

    builder = new StringBuilder(stringa);
    builder[indexEnd] = '.';

    stringhe[idx] = builder.ToString();
    Console.WriteLine("New String: " + stringhe[idx]);
}
```

Or, we can edit the Regex to detect only if the number is followed by a comma with (better anyway)

```
No.\s*([0-9]+),
```

---

I'm not the best at Regex, but this should do what you want.

```
No.\s+([0-9]+)
```

If you except zero or more whitespaces between No. {NUMBER} this Regex should do the work:

```
No.\s*([0-9]+)
```

An example of how can look C# code:

```
string[] stringhe = new string[4] {
    "This is a test No. 42, Hello Nice People",
    "I have no idea wtf No. 1234412344124. I am doing.",
    "Very long No. 74385748957348957893458934; Hello World",
    "Nope No. 48394839!!!"
};

Regex reg = new Regex(@"No.\s+([0-9]+)");

Match match;
int idx = 0;
foreach(string stringa in stringhe)
{
    match = reg.Match(stringa);

    if (match.Success)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("No. Stringa #" + idx + ": " + match.Groups[1].Value);
    }

    ++idx;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. However, the real problem is the 2nd part of my question which is how to I replace the last period in my matches with commas?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code :

```
private string Format(string input)
    {
        Match m = new Regex("No. [0-9]*.").Match(input);

        int targetIndex = m.Index + m.Length - 1;

        return input.Remove(targetIndex, 1).Insert(targetIndex, ",");
    }
```